# connect to elastic search using java on aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to connect elastic search which is installed on AWS ubuntu instance , but I am  not able to connect .

I am trying this:

```
**TransportClient client = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", <clustername>)
                .put("request.headers.X-Found-Cluster", "clustername")
                .build())
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("cloudip"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("cloudip"), 9200));**
```

and getting no node exception.

I found some alternate method that is using restClient but how to insert value using this restClient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it will be better if it will connect with tranportClient.

Comment: no Authentication required for elastic search